# Create a page that asks for user details before the main activity starts

Tags: java, android

I want to create a page that asks for the user to input their details when they first use the app. After that, the app should start and go straight to the main activity every time unless they want to change their details. There will be a dropdown menu for editDetails.

I tried to add image here and apparently I don't have 10 reputation to post images.

SO the user details page will ask for the users name, age, address. And these entries will be saved into the database.

How can I make the editDetails activity appear on first use only? My current MainActivity.java is below

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use shared preferences. Once the user details are entered update  a variable called isSet. For every launch check isSet variable, if it is not set pass intent to editDetails activity.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new activity called FirstLaunchActivity. This activity is started everytime the user launches the app. The activity should check if a file containing the user details exists. IF it does, it should launch MainActivity.

If the file does not exist, it should create a form where the user can enter his information, save it in the user details file and then proceed to MainActivity.

Comment: @jasleen suggested using SharedPreferences for storing the values which is an excllent idea. If these details are username and password, I would recommend encrypting them first.

Comment: I tried having a boolean variable firstUse set to true initially and changes it to false in the if statement below, but it didn't seem to be working. Sry, it's my first time creating Android app.

`public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 
 boolean firstUse = true;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  
  if(firstUse == true) {
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);
   firstUse = false;
  }
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  `

Comment: The problem is that everytime you launch the app, the variable is set to `true` so it assumes that every launch is the first launch. That is why you have to save the value of this boolean variable either in SharedPreferences or in a file and update it as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

2 Ways you could tackle this.

1: Set your `MainActivity` as your MAIN, check to see if you have the details in the DB, launch the user input activity if you don't.

2: Set the user details activity as your MAIN and launch the `MainActivity` if you have user details in the DB.

Comment: How can I launch the DetailsActivity instead of MainActivity first? Will that be all done in the MainActivity.java -> onCreate method?

Comment: Simply move your MAIN and LAUNCHER intent filters in your `AndroidManifext.xml`